# LSTM multi-classification task, input any sample to get the same probability result

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

As shown in the figure below, the data set is a ufc-101 multi-classification problem, and the batch size is 4. When a batch of samples are input, the obtained probability results are the same. The last red box is the label number, which belongs to different categories of samples.

[分类概率分数](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgmSX.png)

The code is as follows, pytorch implementation, the basic LSTM+full connection+softmax structure, the learning rate is 0.0001. I have tried adjusting the learning rate and the number of hidden layers, but none of them can solve the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCgn9.png)

All codes are as follows
Request everyone, I don't know where the problem lies, it has been troubled for several days.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.datasets
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms

import time

DEVICE = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
# DEVICE = "cuda:1"

batch_size = 4
clip_size = 16


def custom_collate(batch):
    filtered_batch = []
    for _video, _, _label in batch:
        filtered_batch.append((_video, _label))
    return torch.utils.data.dataloader.default_collate(filtered_batch)


def accuracy(y_hat, y):
    if len(y_hat.shape) > 1 and y_hat.shape[1] > 1:
        y_hat = y_hat.argmax(axis=1)
    cmp = y_hat.type(y.dtype) == y
    return int(cmp.type(y.dtype).sum())


class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size), nn.Softmax(dim=1))

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.randn(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(DEVICE)
        c0 = torch.randn(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(DEVICE)

        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))

        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Load DataSet")
    dataset = torchvision.datasets.UCF101(root=f'UCF-101', annotation_path=f'annotation', frames_per_clip=clip_size,
                                          step_between_clips=16, train=True, output_format='TCHW')

    test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.UCF101(root=f'UCF-101', annotation_path=f'annotation',
                                               frames_per_clip=clip_size,
                                               step_between_clips=16, train=False, output_format='TCHW')
    print(len(dataset), len(test_dataset))
    video_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=custom_collate)
    video_test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=custom_collate)

    print("Load LSTM")

    hidden_size = 64
    num_layers = 2
    output_size = 101
    input_size = 512
    model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size).to(DEVICE)

    print("Load ResNet")

    resnet = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=False).to(DEVICE)
    resnet.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(512, output_size), nn.Softmax(dim=1))
    resnet.load_state_dict(torch.load('resnet18_pre_17_1.00_0.59.pth'))
    resnet.fc = nn.Sequential()

    PILImg = transforms.ToPILImage()

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    # optimizer1 = torch.optim.Adam(resnet.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
    optimizer2 = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)

    preprocess = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ])

    jl = []
    for epoch in range(1, 500):
        print(f'Begin Train {epoch}')
        train_count, train_true = 0, 0
        t = time.time()
        for i, (video, label) in enumerate(video_dataloader):
            with torch.no_grad():
                len_video = len(video)
                features = torch.zeros(len_video, clip_size, input_size).to(DEVICE)
                for i_batch in range(len_video):
                    feature = torch.zeros(clip_size, 3, 224, 224).to(DEVICE)
                    for j in range(clip_size):
                        feature[j] = preprocess(PILImg(video[i_batch][j]))
                    features[i_batch] = resnet(feature)

            label = label.to(DEVICE)

            outputs = model(features)

            # optimizer1.zero_grad()
            # l1 = criterion(outputs, label)
            # l1.backward(retain_graph=True)
            # optimizer1.step()

            if i != 0 and i % 20 == 0:
                print(f'outputs:{outputs}')
                print(f'label:{label}')

            optimizer2.zero_grad()
            l2 = criterion(outputs, label)
            l2.backward()
            optimizer2.step()

            train_count += len_video
            train_true += accuracy(outputs, label)
            if i != 0 and i % 200 == 0:
                train_ratio = 0 if train_true == 0 else float(train_true) / train_count
                print(
                    f'train_epoch:{epoch}\tloss: {"%.5f" % l2.sum()}\t{train_true}/{train_count}={"%.2f" % train_ratio}\ttime:{int(time.time() - t)}')
                t = time.time()

        train_ratio = 0 if train_true == 0 else float(train_true) / train_count
        jl.append(f'Train_epoch:{epoch}\t{train_true}/{train_count}={"%.2f" % train_ratio}')
        print(jl[-1])

        print(f'Begin Test {epoch}')
        test_count, test_true = 0, 0
        t = time.time()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for i, (test_video, test_label) in enumerate(video_test_dataloader):
                len_test_video = len(test_video)
                features = torch.zeros(len_test_video, clip_size, input_size).to(DEVICE)
                for i_batch in range(len_test_video):
                    feature = torch.zeros(clip_size, 3, 224, 224).to(DEVICE)
                    for j in range(clip_size):
                        feature[j] = preprocess(PILImg(test_video[i_batch][j]))
                    features[i_batch] = resnet(feature)

                test_label = test_label.to(DEVICE)
                outputs = model(features)
                accuracy(outputs, test_label)

                test_count += len_test_video
                test_true += accuracy(outputs, test_label)

                if test_count % 1000 == 0:
                    test_ratio = 0 if test_true == 0 else float(test_true) / test_count
                    print(
                        f'test_epoch:{epoch}\t{test_true}/{test_count}={"%.2f" % test_ratio}\ttime:{int(time.time() - t)}')
                    t = time.time()

            test_ratio = 0 if test_true == 0 else float(test_true) / test_count
            jl.append(f'Test_epoch:{epoch}\t{test_true}/{test_count}={"%.2f" % test_ratio}')
            print(jl[-1])

            train_ratio = 0 if train_true == 0 else float(train_true) / train_count
            torch.save(resnet.state_dict(), f'LR_resnet_{epoch}_{"%.2f" % train_ratio}_{"%.2f" % test_ratio}.pth')
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'LR_lstm_{epoch}_{"%.2f" % train_ratio}_{"%.2f" % test_ratio}.pth')

    [print(line) for line in jl]
```

I have tried adjusting the learning rate and the number of hidden layers, but none of them can solve the problem.